# Typical port forwarding with nftables example

Tags: port-forwarding, nftables

I want to connect to a virtual VM hosted by the server 1.2.3.4 using ssh.
The IP of the VM is 10.10.10.100.

"nft list ruleset" prints:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept comment "Accept any localhost traffic"
        ct state invalid drop comment "Drop invalid connections"
        ct state established,related accept comment "Accept traffic originated from us"
        ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, ind-neighbor-solicit, ind-neighbor-advert, mld2-listener-report } accept comment "Accept ICMPv6"
        ip protocol icmp icmp type { destination-unreachable, router-advertisement, router-solicitation, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept comment "Accept ICMP"
        ip protocol igmp accept comment "Accept IGMP"
        tcp dport ssh accept comment "Accept SSH on port 22"
        tcp dport { http, https, 8008, http-alt } accept comment "Accept HTTP (ports 80, 443, 8008, 8080)"
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain input {
        type nat hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        counter packets 3 bytes 180
    }
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -101; policy accept;
        counter packets 12 bytes 2122
        dnat to tcp dport map { 10100 : 10.10.10.100 }:tcp dport map { 10100 : ssh }
    }
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
        snat to ip saddr map { 1.2.3.4 : 10.10.10.100 }
    }
}
```

"nmap -p10100 1.2.3.4" says: 10100/tcp filtered itap-ddtp

"ssh 1.2.3.4" works.

On Server "ssh 10.10.10.100" works

"sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward" prints "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1"

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the incompatibility of virt-manager and nftables.
virt-manager uses iptables.

Maybe there is a solution.

Using virt-manager is more important for me than using nftables.

Firewalld is Compatible with virt-manager, so in order to use virt-manager, I "must" learn Firewalld.

Answer (score 0):

Just created an account to try to answer your question. I had a similar problem. what I think you're missing is to allow the IP in the forward chain. Something like:

```
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        ip daddr 10.10.10.100 ct status dnat accept;
    }
```

Hope this help with your issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/577252)